# How do I check rebuild is complete after losing a replica?

Tags: rebuild, openebs, crash-recovery

I am using OpenEBS with Jiva. I have MySQL pod running on OpenEBS with 3 replicas. My DB is around 10GB with the actual volume size ~30GB

After I lose a replica, new replica span up. Assuming that it starts replicating data immediately;
1) How do I know rebuild is done and it's safe to say ? 
2) What is the average time to complete a replica rebuild on AWS (using EBS volumes) per 10 GB of data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to exec this example on you `openebs-apiserver`:

```
mayactl --namespace stolon --volname my-data-my-service-0-1559496748 volume stats
```

End got result:

```
Executing volume stats...

Portal Details :
---------------
IQN     :   iqn.2016-09.com.openebs.jiva:my-data-my-service-0-1559496748
Volume  :   my-data-my-service-0-1559496748
Portal  :   10.43.111.28:3260
Size    :   70Gi


Replica Stats :
----------------
REPLICA        STATUS      DATAUPDATEINDEX
--------       -------     ----------------
10.42.7.56     running     1784
10.42.9.13     running     1266322
10.42.3.13     running     1266322


Performance Stats :
--------------------
r/s      w/s      r(MB/s)      w(MB/s)      rLat(ms)      wLat(ms)
----     ----     --------     --------     ---------     ---------
0        22       0.000        0.188        0.000         7.625


Capacity Stats :
---------------
LOGICAL(GB)      USED(GB)
------------     ---------
77.834           65.966
```

From this example you can see that this replica not ready with DATAUPDATEINDEX

```
10.42.7.56     running     1784
```